# How to change a docker ARG value inside an if statement?

Tags: docker, docker-build

In my Dockerfile on *Ubuntu 16.04* with *docker 17.12.1-ce* I use

```
ARG ver=latest
ARG pkg=master
```

For building a docker container, I would like to call `docker build --build-arg ver=v1 .` in order to set a special package.

The code-handling part in my Dockerfile is

```
RUN if[ "x$ver" = "xv1" ] ; then pkg=v1.2.3 ; fi
RUN echo $pkg
```

Unfortunately, the **ARG pkg** variable is not updated and the echo statement always shows its initial value.

What can I do, to update my build variable **pkg** inside an if statement??

Answer (score 3):

You will not be able to pass variables from one `RUN` to another because each `RUN` command is executed in a different shell. 
A solution to your problem would be to extract the logic into a script and execute docker with the build arguments something like this:

```
if [ $ver="v1" ]; then pkg=1.2.3; fi; docker build --build-arg ver=$ver --build-arg pkg=$pkg .
```

Comment: Somehow, I would have hoped, that ARG variables are in the scope of the whole build process, not only within a single RUN statement?

Comment: Dockerfile has limitations. If you need more flexibility, you could use a _template_ format [dockerfile-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerfile-template) or write Dockerfile in bash [bocker](https://github.com/icy/bocker)